# finite dimensionality of $ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$ $\implies$ finite dimensionality of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that there exists a *Linear-Transformation*, $T:V\to V$ such that $null\ T$ and $range\ T$ are both *finite-dimensional* it follows that $V$ is *finite-dimensional*.

**Proof.** Let $v$ be arbitrary and assume that $v\in V$ thus for some $w\in\ range\ T$, $Tv = w$ we know that $range\ T$ is *finite-dimensional* thus for some $w_1,w_2,...,w_m\in\ range\ T$ we have
$$Tv = \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jw_j\tag{1}$$
moreover since $w_j\in\ range\ T$ it follows that $\forall j\in\{1,2,...,m\}\exists v_j(w_j=Tv_j)$ consequently we may write $(2)$ as follows 
$$Tv = \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jTv_j\tag{2}$$
which implies that 
$$Tv -\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jTv_j=0\tag{3}$$
$$T\left(v -\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jv_j\right)=0\tag{4}$$
evidently $(v -\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jv_j)\in\ null\ T$ and we know that $null\ T$ is *finite-dimensional* thus for some $u_1,u_2,...,u_n\in\ null\ T$ it is the case that 
$$v -\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jv_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_iu_i\tag{5}$$
hence
$$v =\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jv_j+\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_iu_i\tag{6}$$
from which we may infer that $span(v_1,v_2,...,v_m,u_1,u_2,...,u_n)=V$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: In (4), the summand should be $a_j v_j$ because you have (un-)distributed $T$ to the outside of the parens.  Just before eqn (2), when you write "we may write (2) as follows", do you mean "(1)"?

Comment: Apologies All Corrections have been made